Как расценить союзы ИЛИ и И (фраза конкретная)?
Прошу помощи в правильном понимании ниже указанного предложения:
«... имеющих высшее образование по направлению подготовки "Филология" или "Лингвистика", "История", "Юриспруденция" и получивших дополнительное профессиональное образование»...
В данном случае, интересуют запятые после слов: лингвистика, история, юриспруденция. Они считаются как союз ИЛИ или как И??? Т.е.: 1. филологии ИЛИ лингвистика И история И юриспруденция;
2. филология ИЛИ лингвистика ИЛИ история ИЛИ юриспруденция.
Заранее благодарю))

Союз или и и в данном случае объединяют однородные члены предложения: союз или объединяет однородные определения  филология или лингвистика,  союз же и объединяет однородные сказуемые  имеющих...  и получивших.  Это разные союзы, выполняющие разную роль.
Корректно: «... имеющих высшее образование по направлению подготовки "Филология" или "Лингвистика", "История", "Юриспруденция" и получивших дополнительное профессиональное образование»...

Серж, вы не поняли вопрос.

@Aлександр Стрелец, по-видимому, автор спрашивает о том,является ли цельным союз или ...и или это отдельные союзы. Автор пока молчит.

@Серж, мне кажется нужно в ответе нужно записать фрагмент предложения с расставленными знаками и объяснить функцию каждого знака. Тогда не будет вопросов.

В этом фрагменте текста интересуют запятые... понятно, что идёт перечисление... но там подразумевается "И" или "ИЛИ"? Там пример 1 и пример 2 прочтения... подскажите, как правильно ???
